# Using active directory from command prompt - dsquery user - how to get everyone except x?

Tags: active-directory, dsquery

Using the example from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755655(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_7

```
dsquery user OU=Test,DC=Microsoft,DC=Com -name jon
```

What i want is everyone but jon. The following did not work:

```
dsquery user OU=Test,DC=Microsoft,DC=Com -name !jon
```

Is it possible from cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding a for loop with an if statement. Not an answer as such but it works.